# odata service ignores sorting definition in sql view (SAP HANA Cloud Platform)

Tags: sql, odata, hana, sap-cloud-platform

My first step to learning SAP HANA was usage of odata services related to database tables and database views.
I created the XS Project, then a database table, fill it with content and then created the sql view and definded simple odata service *topowners.xsodata*.
The sql view was grouped and ordered. 
If i call (in Eclispe or WebIDE) the sql view "display content" , the entries are correct ordered by defined attribute.

If is call the odata service in XS Service (in browser) the entries are NOT ordered by defined attribute. How do I solve the problem? Thank you

---

### odata Service definition

```
service { 
"DB_XS"."SUM_VIEW" as "TopOwners"
key  ("owner_code") 
    create forbidden
    update forbidden
    delete forbidden;
}
```

---

### sql view definition

```
CREATE VIEW "DB_XS"."SUM_VIEW" ( "owner_code",
     "owner_count"
) AS select
     owners."owner_code" ,
     SUM("current_owner_cnt") as "owner_count"  

from "DB_XS"."owners" owners 

group by owners."owner_code"  

order by "owner_count" desc 
     p WITH READ ONLY
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the problem by adding a `$orderby` in your oData request:

```
 http:// ... /topowners.xsodata/TopOwners?$orderby=owner_count
```

See [here](http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/hana/blog/2014/06/11/introduction-to-hana-xs-application-development-part-5-blogproject-exposing-data-with-odata-services-and-performing-crud-operations-from-ui) for example